# How to ignore certain paths during Branch Indexing in Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have an organizational project configured in Jenkins which scans repositories for jenkinsfile. One of the repository (https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-module-jenkinssample) has a following Jenkinsfile defined:

```
node 
{
    stage 'Checkout'
        checkout([
            $class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
            extensions: [[
                $class: 'PathRestriction', 
                excludedRegions: 'CommonAssemblyInfo\\.cs', 
                includedRegions: ''
            ]], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [[
                url: 'git@github.com:VirtoCommerce/vc-module-jenkinssample.git']]])
}
```

As you might see I have an excluded region defined, so changes made to CommonAssemblyInfo.cs don't trigger any builds. However "Branch Indexing" still forces the job to build when I commit changes to "CommonAssemblyInfo.cs". How can I prevent this?

Btw, the above script works fine in a separate Pipeline Job.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to ignore build when using organizational package. However I was able to capture comments on the second build (after commit from the 1st build) and not commit again so infinite loop is prevented. To do that I read the last comment and made sure it is not what I what I expect:

```
bat "\"${tool 'Git'}\" log -1 --pretty=%%B > LAST_COMMIT_MESSAGE"
git_last_commit=readFile('LAST_COMMIT_MESSAGE')

if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' && git_last_commit.contains('[publish]'))
{
    stage 'Publishing'
        processManifests()
}
}
```

Hope this helps someone.